# Add information from autocomplete to new line

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
can't add information from autocomplete to new line
```

ekle butonuna tıkladığımda aşağıda boş div ekliyor. otamatik tamamlamada gelen bilgileri eklemesini istiyorum

```
**it works when I press the first insert button but then adds a hollow div**
```

Format your code:

```js
<script>
  $( function() {
   function log( message ) {
                     $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#envid_" );      
                 }
                 function log2( message ) {
                     $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#logid_" );
                 }
                    $( "#envara" ).autocomplete({
                     source: "listeleme",
                    minLength: 1,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                    log2(  " ADI= " + ui.item.ad + " SITE ID = " + ui.item.siteid + " PROJE = " + ui.item.proje + " AÇIKLAMA = " + ui.item.aciklama);
                    log(  "" + ui.item.value);                   
                    }                   
                    });
                    var sayac = 1; 
                $('#ekle2').click(function() {
                    sayac ++;
                    function log( message ) {
                            $('#envid_').attr('id','envid_'+sayac);                            

                     $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#envid_" );     
                 }
                 function log2( message ) {
                    $('#logid_').attr('id','logid_'+sayac);
                     $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#logid_" );    
                 }
                    $( "#envara" ).autocomplete({
                     source: "listeleme",
                    minLength: 1,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                    log2(  " ADI= " + ui.item.ad + " SITE ID = " + ui.item.siteid + " PROJE = " + ui.item.proje + " AÇIKLAMA = " + ui.item.aciklama);
                    log(  "" + ui.item.value);               
                    }                   
                    });
                    $('#env_takip tbody').append(
                        '<tr><th><strong>Env ' + sayac + '</strong></th>' +
                        '<td><div id="envid_' + sayac + '" name="envid[]' + '"class="callout callout-info" ></div></td>' +
                        '<td><input id="envNot_' + sayac + '" name="envNot[]' + '" type="text" class="form-control"  /></td>' +
                        '<td><div id="logid_' + sayac + '" name="log[]' + '"class="callout callout-info" ></div></td>' +
                        '<td><a href="#" class="sil btn btn-danger">Sil</a></td></tr>');
                });                             
  } );
  </script>
ekle butonuna tıkladığımda aşağıda boş div ekliyor. otamatik tamamlamada gelen bilgileri eklemesini istiyorum
ekle butonuna tıkladığımda aşağıda boş div ekliyor. otamatik tamamlamada gelen bilgileri eklemesini istiyorum
```

```html
<table id="env_takip" class="table table-condensed">
                                    <thead>
                                    <td></td>
                                        <td><input id="envara" name="envara[]" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p id="ekle2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">&raquo; Ekle</a></p>                                           
                                        </td>                                      
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><strong>Env 1</strong></th>
                                        <td><div id="envid_" name="envid[]" class="callout callout-info"></div></td> 
                                        <td><input id="envNot_" name="envNot[]" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><div id="logid_" name="logid[]" class="callout callout-info"></div></td>
                                    </tr> 
                                    </tbody>                                   
                                </table>
```